# Drag a formula, so that it increases by 17 each time

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following formulas on the third sheet of my workbook. They are simply cell references to the first sheet; on my 'output' page, I want to display every 17th cell of the 'input' sheet. However when I drag the formula down, it goes up in 2's. Any help gratefully appreciated.

```
=Input!B2   =Input!F10   =Input!F6   =Input!H11   =Input!F4   =Input!F13   =Input!F8
=Input!B19  =Input!F27   =Input!F23  =Input!H28   =Input!F21  =Input!F30   =Input!F25
```

(The use case is that I have "records" on the 'Input' sheet that are 17 rows high,
and I want to display summary data on the 'Output' sheet in a one-row-per-record arrangement.)

Comment: The alignment makes the example hard to follow, but what you show seems to contain references to cells 17 rows apart.  The are no formulas shown, just cell references.  Can you clarify what's there, what you do, and what you get when you do what you do?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  You are correct, I should've said cell references. I want to display the cell B2 from the first sheet, on A1 on the 3rd sheet. Then I want to jump 17 spaces on the first sheet, and display cell B19, and have that display on A2 on the 3rd sheet. And when I drag down, I would like A1, A2, A3 to increase by 17 each time on their own.

Comment: Does teylyn's answer give you what you need?  If not, please clarify what doesn't work or what you don't understand.  If it answers the question, you can click the checkmark to indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: As an example, on sheet 1 of my workbook I have a name in cell B2, followed by phone number of the same person in F6 and lots of other information in the cells between. I would like to extrapolate only the name and phone number and display them on sheet 3 in adjacent cells. Then carry that on down the page on sheet 3. If I drag my current cell references, they just go up in 2's. Teylyn's solution certainly works within the same sheet, and if I can get it working I will let you both know. your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will return A17. When draged down it will return the values in A34, A51, A68, etc. i.e. every 17th row.

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()*17))
```

If you want to start in a different row, say row 10, you need to subtract the respective number from the starting row, like 7.

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW()*17)-7)
```