# How to increase the excel value 1 after to leave the few cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I enter the following data on a sheet:

```
 Roll-No:-   801 
       Maximum Marks
            20
            20 
            20 
            20 
            20 
            20 
         Sig. of Class
    Incharge
```

When I try to drag the cells to copy the same block of cells below the original block, the number after `Roll-No:-` becomes `814`, but I expected to be `802`, like this:

```
    Roll-No:- 814 
       Maximum Marks
            20
            20 
            20 
            20 
            20 
            20 
         Sig. of Class
```

Which formula is the best during drag or paste the rows, so after 14 Rows the Roll number increase to `802`? If u want I can send you a copy of the sheet.

Comment: `Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.`

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/858318/drag-a-formula-so-that-it-increases-by-17-each-time.  The problem was slightly different, but it also called for calculating an adjusted row number rather than using the raw row relationship.  The basic technique in the answer can be modified to do what you want.  If you need additional help to adapt it to your problem, post back.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem in Excel 2007. If I select the entire block of text and fill down, 801 is incremented to 802 as you desire.

Comment: @Excellll - It looks like he's got a block of stuff and dragging the header information, which contains a cell reference, 13 rows to the next block position.  The cell reference reflects the 13 row move, but he wants to increment the value by only one because it is the next block.

Answer (score 0):

its not clear if your roll number and value are in one cell, assuming they are in B28 you could use:-

="Roll-No:-      "&VALUE(RIGHT(B14,5))+1

and copy the block