# Copy formula down, skipping cells but have it pull data in single increments from other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a time sheet I'm helping to create, and it pulls data from sheet 1 and adds it to a list on sheet 2.  The data needs to reference  sheet 1 at A42, then A73, A115, A146, A188, etc., following a spacing pattern of 42, then 31, then 42, then 31; 100 instances of this. How can I reference data in this way?

Comment: You should update your question so that it correctly describes what you want.

Comment: Sorry, it was totally backward before and didnt realize I could update it.  My question is fixed now, thank you.

Comment: I don't see any edits made to he question so far...

Comment: Went ahead and edited it again, not sure what happened before but now its reading correct.

Comment: I think the gist of how to do what you want is covered here: http://superuser.com/questions/858318/drag-a-formula-so-that-it-increases-by-17-each-time

Comment: @fixer1234, while that totally works if I had a set number of rows on sheet1, its not working for this particular problem.  However, I was able to get it work following this pattern: =INDEX(Bill!S:S,(ROW()*31)+11), then repeat that once more, =INDEX(Bill!S:S,(ROW()*31)+22) then repeat that once more, =INDEX(Bill!S:S,(ROW()*31)+33) then repeat that once more and so on.  If there was a way I could get that row number variable to go up by 11 rows every second row I drag it to i should be golden.

Comment: That just takes clever arithmetic.  I'm a little confused, though, on the exact pattern you need to handle.  Could you maybe add to the question a list of cells or rows that need to be copied (not 100 of them, but a big enough list so the pattern is clear)?

Comment: That could work, but the problem is trying to find a way to reference the data that is 30 rows between, then 41, then 30, which means even going back to the formula pattern of 30 rows for the next 2 would be wrong because the 41 space created a 71 since my previous 30 count.

Comment: I'm also a little confused of the configuration of data in Sheet1. You give an example of rows being 1, 14 and 27, but on the other hand you say that the pattern is 30 rows between, 41 rows between, again 30 rows between... and those two claims don't match.

Comment: If there is a pattern (or pattern within a pattern), it can probably be done with formulas.  If it is a random collection of rows but the applicable rows don't change, it could be done with a list.  If it is a random collection of rows and the applicable rows can change, you might be able to automate it a little with macros.  The only way people will be able to figure out a solution is if you provide something like a list of what the applicable rows would be; enough of them to understand any patterns.

Comment: I only used those cell numbers as an example, shouldve been more specific.  So going back through it, everything starts on the reference sheet (sheet1) at A42, then A73, A115, A146, A188, etc, following a pattern of 42, then 31, then 42, then 31; 100 repeating instances of this pattern.  It needs to be referenced (on sheet2) in cells B23-B123 in single increments.  Sorry I wasnt very specific originally, I was really looking for the correct way to do it not specifically the formula to solve it, was kinda going to try it on my own with a little direction.  I just didnt know where to start.

Comment: This is a good example of why the question needs to state the problem accurately. Now, after three revisions for the three versions of your question, I hope my answer helps you in getting the results you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems that there is a constant pattern with the Sheet1 cells you need to reference, it is just a matter of constructing a formula to produce the correct Sheet1 row number based on the row number of Sheet2. It is rather easy to produce the referencing formula using some of functions `ROW()`, `ISEVEN()` or `ISODD()`, `MOD()` and `FLOOR()`.

row number of Sheet1 = `31*FLOOR((ROW())/2;1)+42*FLOOR((ROW()+1)/2;1)`

From the row number to actual formula with `INDEX()` function:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;30*FLOOR(ROW()/2;1)+41*FLOOR((ROW()-1)/2;1)+42;1)`

(in the formula, you obviously need to modify the range of the first parameter to fit your source data, and the number in the last parameter which states the number of the column in the range).

As the row number of Sheet2 is a main factor in getting the correct row in Sheet1, the above works only when the source data in Sheet1 starts at row 42 and the result data in Sheet2 starts at row 1. If that changes, you could of course subtract the row offset in the formula for each call to `ROW()` (for offset in Sheet2) and/or add/subtract to the resulting row number (for offset change in Sheet1).

Comment: Actually looking at it I think I totally explained it backward.  The data needs to reference cells sheet1A1, sheet1A14, sheet1A27, etc etc and be listed as sheet2B1, sheet2B2, sheet2B3....I was having trouble finding how to reference cells on sheet 1 with variable distances between and have then end up on sheet 2.  Some have 30 rows between, some have 41, then 30, then 41 and so on.

Comment: @user496412 I can update my answer later on, but please do fix the question first.

Comment: @user496412 I have now updated my answer. Please try it out.

Comment: You were first with the concept and put in a lot of effort as the question was refined.  +1

Comment: Sweet, with a little tweaking for my specific problem that did it perfectly, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you could do it with formulas:

[image]

I'm using column A to illustrate the pattern that the meat of the formula produces.  This starts in row 2 since row 1 would probably contain headings.  This would be on sheet 2 where you want to build a list of items selected from sheet 1.  The formula in A2 that calculates the target row numbers is:

```
=INT(ROW()/2)*42+INT((ROW()-1)/2)*31
```

The next screenshot illustrates how you would use that to actually pull a cell from the other sheet:

[image]

I stuck something to copy only in cell A42, which is why only one cell is filled in column B.  The formula uses the INDIRECT function to build a cell reference.  The formula in B2 is:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!A" & INT(ROW()/2)*42+INT((ROW()-1)/2)*31)
```

Cell A42 of sheet 1 contains `ABC`.

Comment: I was playing with this in the background as the question was being refined.  @zagrimsan's answer updated to the current version after I posted this.  It looks like great minds think alike. This is the same concept, but we started with different rows and used slightly different formulas.  Like most things in Excel, you can use a number of different functions to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I didn't think of using `INT()` which is nice for shortness. And I do think your solution is more elegant (I was thinking of adding in my answer that it's likely not even near the shortest or prettiest one).

Comment: This one worked just as well, thanks to both of you!