# ISO Copying formula problems

Tags: microsoft-excel

Formulas do not act like I want when copied. These formulas work but when copied do not increment the way I need. As you can see I need the `ROW(20:20)` to increase by 1 to `ROW(21:21)` in the next cell, then by 8 to `ROW(29:29)` then by 1 then by 9 so on and so forth.  Also I need the `MATCH(A5,` to increase to A7 when the row increases by 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated. or if there is an easier way to do this... Thank you in advance.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500,SMALL(IF(MATCH(A5,Sheet2!A:A,0),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500)),ROW(20:20))-1,13),"Error")}

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500,SMALL(IF(MATCH(A5,Sheet2!A:A,0),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500)),ROW(21:21))-1,13),"Error")}

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500,SMALL(IF(MATCH(A7,Sheet2!A:A,0),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500)),ROW(29:29))-1,13),"Error")}

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500,SMALL(IF(MATCH(A7,Sheet2!A:A,0),ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$Z$500)),ROW(30:30))-1,13),"Error")}
```

Comment: Why such a vague title for an Excel.question

Comment: I think the gist of a solution can be found in http://superuser.com/questions/858318/drag-a-formula-so-that-it-increases-by-17-each-time or http://superuser.com/questions/971869/copy-formula-down-skipping-cells-but-have-it-pull-data-in-single-increments-fro